# How to solve cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x 0C910BD0> error?

Tags: python, keras

I downloaded images for training the model in keras (I collected them from google images using an extension). Then I used the code to resize.

```
from PIL import Image
import os, sys

path = "C:\\Users\\Администратор\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\1\\"
out = "C:\\Users\\Администратор\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\1_resized\\"


dirs = os.listdir( path )

def resize():
    for item in dirs:
        if os.path.isfile(path+item):
            im = Image.open(path+item)
            f, e = os.path.splitext(path+item)
            imResize = im.resize((36,36), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            imResize.save(out + item, 'JPEG', quality=90)

resize()
```

And then ran the main code.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import os
import keras 
import joblib
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator


train_images = 'C:\\Users\\Администратор\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\train_images'

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(36, 36, 3)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1. /255)

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
  train_images,
  target_size = (36,36),
  batch_size = 4,
  class_mode = 'binary')

model.fit(np.array(train_generator), epochs=10, validation_split = 0.1)
```

Error(cmd).

```
C:\Users\Администратор>C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\image_guess.py
Using Theano backend.
WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not available, if using conda: `conda install m2w64-toolchain`
C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\theano\configdefaults.py:560: UserWarning: DeprecationWarning: there is no c++ compiler.This is deprecated and with Theano 0.11 a c++ compiler will be mandatory
      warnings.warn("DeprecationWarning: there is no c++ compiler."
    WARNING (theano.configdefaults): g++ not detected ! Theano will be unable to execute optimized C-implementations (for both CPU and GPU) and will default to Python implementations. Performance will be severely degraded. To remove this warning, set Theano flags cxx to an empty string.
    WARNING (theano.tensor.blas): Using NumPy C-API based implementation for BLAS functions.
    Found 339 images belonging to 2 classes.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\image_guess.py", 
        line 32, in <module>
        model.fit(np.array(train_generator), epochs=10, validation_split = 0.1)
      File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\iterator.py", 
        line 104, in __next__
        return self.next(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\iterator.py", 
        line 116, in next
        return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)
      File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\iterator.py", 
        line 230, in _get_batches_of_transformed_samples
        interpolation=self.interpolation)
      File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\utils.py", 
        line 114, in load_img
        img = pil_image.open(io.BytesIO(f.read()))
      File "C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", 
        line 2944, in open
        "cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp)
    PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x0C910BD0>
```

Comment: Can you list the files on train_images folder?

Comment: @demokritos thanks. I found a broken image in the folder with the code below.

Answer (score 0):

I found a broken image in the folder with the code below. By deleting it the problem was solved.

```
import glob
from PIL import Image

imagepath = 'C:\\Users\\Администратор\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\train_images\\' 

imgs_names = glob.glob(imagepath+'\\*.jpg')

for imgname in imgs_names: 
    img = Image.open(imgname) 
    if img is None:     
        print(imgname)
```